# auto-update date field on create/update row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, heroku-postgres

i would like on row creation or alteration to have specific datetime fields updated.. i.e. on row insertion, i would have created_at and updated_at setted to the UTC datetime of creation. On row alter, i'd update only updated_at field. How can i do so?

Comment: Use a trigger, the manual contains an example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name awesome! thanks! Can you post your comment as an answer so that i can check it?